# What’s the appropriate tag to use for questions about political mottos or slogans?

Tags: support, tags

I asked this [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54262/has-don-t-tread-on-me-a-specific-political-color) about the phrase "Don't tread on me" but I couldn’t find an appropriate tag such as “political motto or slogan, so I used [history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) instead. Is there a more appropriate one or should a new one be put in place?

Comment: The [tag:rhetoric] tag would have been fairly ok imho.

Answer (score 4):

It might be worthwhile to make a new tag here. [slogan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slogan) seems appropriate

Comment: Sure, I have no objections. Should the tag wiki say a bit more about what kinds of questions about slogans are on topic?

Comment: @divibisan If you want to expand the Excerpt I have no problem with that